# How do I upload a file through a form and have Java process it as an InputStream?

Tags: java, http, streaming, inputstream

I have a Java class that accepts an InputStream and encodes the data coming in. How do I get something working that will accept a file upload from the user, but treat it as a stream without saving the whole thing to disk first and using FileInputStream?

Basically I'm looking for some lightweight web framework in Java that will just let me get a file uploaded by the user as a data stream.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If not done yet, install a webserver/servletcontainer like [Apache Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org).

If you pick Tomcat 6.x, then use [Apache Commons FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload) to get the uploaded file as an `InputStream`. If you pick Tomcat 7.x (Servlet 3.0), then use [`HttpServletRequest#getPart()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getPart%28java.lang.String%29) and then [`Part#getInputStream()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/Part.html#getInputStream%28%29) to obtain the uploaded file as an `InputStream`.

Answer (score 2):

```
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItemStream;
 import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItemIterator;
 import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;

 import java.io.InputStream;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.util.logging.Logger;

 import javax.servlet.ServletException;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

 public class FileUpload extends HttpServlet {
   private static final Logger log =
       Logger.getLogger(FileUpload.class.getName());

   public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
       throws ServletException, IOException {
     try {
       ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload();
       res.setContentType("text/plain");

       FileItemIterator iterator = upload.getItemIterator(req);
       while (iterator.hasNext()) {
         FileItemStream item = iterator.next();
         InputStream stream = item.openStream();

         if (item.isFormField()) {
           log.warning("Got a form field: " + item.getFieldName());
         } else {
           log.warning("Got an uploaded file: " + item.getFieldName() +
                       ", name = " + item.getName());

           // You now have the filename (item.getName() and the
           // contents (which you can read from stream).  Here we just
           // print them back out to the servlet output stream, but you
           // will probably want to do something more interesting (for
           // example, wrap them in a Blob and commit them to the
           // datastore).
           int len;
           byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
           while ((len = stream.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1) {
             res.getOutputStream().write(buffer, 0, len);
           }
         }
       }
     } catch (Exception ex) {
       throw new ServletException(ex);
     }
   }
 }
```

The example is extracted from Google App Engine documents since GAE also doesn't allow the application to write files on disk. The original example can be found [here](http://code.google.com/intl/fr/appengine/kb/java.html#fileforms)